# Is it possible to enable dual channel recording with following code

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I am able to call a number with following code from the link
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls

Is it possible to enable dual channel recording with following code ?. if yes, how ?

```
SDK Version: 6.x 7.x
// Install the Java helper library from twilio.com/docs/java/install
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

public class Example {
  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACd6b6b7dc8ae6f3e6f7ff72c8dbbd457f";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Call call = Call.creator(new PhoneNumber("+14155551212"), new PhoneNumber("+15017250604"),
        new URI("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")).create();

    System.out.println(call.getSid());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are missing the parameter to record the call in your API call here. When building the call object you need something like the following:

```
Call call = Call.creator(
  new PhoneNumber("+14155551212"),
  new PhoneNumber("+15017250604"),
  new URI("https://example.com/voice")
)
.setRecord(true)
.setRecordingChannels("dual")
.setRecordingStatusCallback("https://example.com/recording")
.create();
```

The URL that you pass to the call creator should point at an application that you control as well. This application needs to return [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) that will connect the first call to another to give you the two legs to record. You need to use [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) with either [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number), [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client), [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip) or [`<Sim>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sim). Like this:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>NUMBER TO CONNECT TO</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Following coe helps me connect to gotomeeting. Why do i need to configure TwiML if call is already connected and dual channel recording is also configured using Call.creator. `code` Call call = Call.creator(
  new PhoneNumber(FROM_NUMBER),
  new PhoneNumber(TO_NUMBER),
  new URI("https://example.com/voice")
)
.setRecord(true)
.setRecordingChannels("dual").setSendDigits("1234")
.setRecordingStatusCallback("https://example.com/recording")
.create(); `code`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. What is your full use case here and what are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: I would like Twilio number to programmatically call GTM and start recording on dual channel.

Comment: So you want to call into an existing conference run by GoToMeeting and record your end of the call and in a different channel, everyone else in the meeting?

Comment: You can drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com and I'll try to help :)